# Saved proxy settings for SSH with various AWS accounts

Tags: ssh, proxy, amazon-ec2

I manage EC2 instances (virtual machines) across a number of Amazon accounts. The machines don't necessarily have domain names; usually I connect to them by IP address.

Each AWS account has its own bastion server that I connect through. It's annoying, because when I connect to a machine I have to specify the settings for the SSH tunnel on the command line. If the machines had domain names, I would just configure the tunnel in my `~/.ssh/config` file. Instead, I have to do this - and the proxy IP address changes depending on which AWS account I'm working on:

```
ssh -o ProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p ubuntu@1.2.3.4" ubuntu@172.17.1.2
```

Is there a nice way to configure SSH so I don't need to specify the proxy command (and maybe the user name)? I'm happy to use another solution such as a bash alias if that makes more sense.

Answer (score 1):

This is exactly what you have `~/.ssh/config` for. It is not clear what problems do you have with it, but something like

```
Host proxy1
  Hostname 1.2.3.4
  User ubuntu

Host target1
  Hostname 172.17.1.2
  ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p proxy1
  User ubuntu
```

And then connect just using `ssh target1`. Of course you can match more targets with the single proxy, define different aliases or use wildcards (`Host 172.17.1.*`) to match whole IP blocks.

Comment: The problem is that I don't know what IP ranges my machines will have when I spin them up, and a private IP address might be shared by machines on different AWS accounts.

Answer (score 0):

I've added these aliases to my `.bashrc` file:

```
alias ssh-foo='ssh -o ProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p -l ubuntu <FOO_BASTION_IP>" -l ubuntu'
alias ssh-bar='ssh -o ProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p -l ubuntu <BAR_BASTION_IP>" -l ubuntu'
```

Now the command to connect is as simple as:

```
ssh-foo <FOO_INSTANCE_IP>
```

The alias for `scp` is similar but the user name needs to be given differently:

```
alias scp-bar='scp -o ProxyCommand="ssh -W %h:%p -l ubuntu <BAR_BASTION_IP>" -o User=ubuntu'
```

Answer (score 0):

Like the .bashrc option mentioned earlier too. For something different:

Modify your hosts file to include friendly names as you want.

```
sudo vi /etc/hosts
```

Create a few different text files with your ssh script in it.
**Created a text file**:

`sudo echo "ssh -o ProxyCommand=\"ssh -W %h:%p ubuntu@1.2.3.4\" " > your-ssh-file`

**Make it executable**
`sudo chmod +x your-ssh-file`

**Execute the file in the folder you created it with a:**
`./your-ssh-file`